# What is the purpose of these extra curly braces within an else block?

Tags: javascript, typescript, syntax, scope

I'm looking over some typescript code, and I see extra curly braces being used within an else block. Do these extra braces serve any purpose? Or are they simply to add extra grouping to two almost identical code snippets? Given that this is a very popular Microsoft repo, it doubt its accidental.

```
  if (playwrightTestPackagePath) {
    require(playwrightTestPackagePath).addTestCommand(program);
    require(playwrightTestPackagePath).addShowReportCommand(program);
    require(playwrightTestPackagePath).addListFilesCommand(program);
  } else {
    {
      const command = program.command('test').allowUnknownOption(true);
      command.description('Run tests with Playwright Test. Available in @playwright/test package.');
      command.action(async () => {
        console.error('Please install @playwright/test package to use Playwright Test.');
        console.error('  npm install -D @playwright/test');
        process.exit(1);
      });
    }

    {
      const command = program.command('show-report').allowUnknownOption(true);
      command.description('Show Playwright Test HTML report. Available in @playwright/test package.');
      command.action(async () => {
        console.error('Please install @playwright/test package to use Playwright Test.');
        console.error('  npm install -D @playwright/test');
        process.exit(1);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/6a60de1b2fe9436c52b80351249b0d84a072afc5/packages/playwright-core/src/cli/cli.ts#L321-L338)

Comment: Those create blocks where each block has it's own variable scope. If you didn't have them, the second `const command =` declaration would produce an error since a const variable of that name had already been assigned earlier.

Comment: But it's awkward at best, it would be clearer to use descriptive variable names for each command.

Comment: "*Do these extra braces serve any purpose?*" - try to omit them and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just block for creating new scope for variables. You can see `const command = ...` - this can't be in one scope or error will be thrown: `SyntaxError: redeclaration of const command`.

```js
// no errors
{
  const x = 1;
  console.log(x) // 1
}
{
  const x = 2;
  console.log(x) // 2
}
{
  const x = 3;
  console.log(x) // 3
}

// error
const x = 1
const x = 2 // Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of const x
const x = 3
```

I think it's just for avoiding naming like `command2, command3` etc.